# C# Visual studio 2017 crash when custom user control throw exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crash, custom-controls

I am learning write my own user controls , and i find that when i throw exception  during designer view,  Visual studio 2017 will stop working. 
I created a user control called  "ColoredProgressBar" . 

When **AnimationStyle** was set to **ProgressBarAnimationStyle.Instantly** and **TextStyle** was set **ProgressBarTextStyle.AnimationPercentage** then the class will throw a 
InvalidStyleCombinationException(this is my custom exception). 
Here is my code :

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // . . . 
        if (this.AnimationStyle == SUPEXFunction.UI.ProgressBarAnimationStyle.Instantly && this.TextStyle == SUPEXFunction.UI.ProgressBarTextStyle.AnimationPercentage)
        {
            this.AnimationReachedValue = 0;
            InvalidStyleCombinationException a = new InvalidStyleCombinationException("ProgressBarAnimationStyle.Instantly and ProgressBarTextStyle.AnimationPercentage can't exist in same time .");
            throw a;
        }
        // . . . 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
public ColoredProgressBar()
{
    this.First = true;
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    this.timer.Interval = 1;
    this.timer.Start();
    this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
}
```

Is this a bug of VS 2017 ?
How can i fix this without remove the exception ?

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is occurred at compile time ?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQymlM0TbJo&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Your code has nothing to make VS 2017 to crash , No infinite loops nothing as I can see.
Try updating your VS2017 with the latest update 2 days ago.
It will work just fine.

Comment: I update my VS 2017 to latest version , and VS is still stop working when i set AnimationStyle to ProgressBarAnimationStyle.Instantly and TextStyle to ProgressBarTextStyle.AnimationPercentage . 
Like this :  youtube.com/watch?v=SQymlM0TbJo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Best thing to do now is reporting such issue to VS team.